# Page did not fire its load event but in the app preview section page seems to load in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

When I try to run the tests on a page in the command log of Cypress runner, the cy.visit is executed and the page loads on the right side of the app preview, but the cy.visit is still waiting  for page to load and it eventually returns an error.

I added cy.wait, see if there is a way to see if the load event is fired or not ?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3ajT.png)

Timed out after waiting 120000ms for your remote page to load.
Your page did not fire its load event within 120000ms.